# Getting post data from request

Tags: java, post, apache-httpcomponents

I'm writing a server side app in Java using the HttpCore library. 
I have an HttpRequest and I'm trying to get the postdata sent from a form. The problem is- when I use `request.getEntity()` it returns a null object, even though when I look through HTTPFox on what kind of request I'm sending the post data is clearly there.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show us some more code! What do you do with the request before that call is made?

Comment: @Vincent I rescanned the code and the answer is: only reading the headers.

Comment: Please just post the sourcecode. You might be doing something you're not aware of. Anything that's dealing with that request variable would be useful :)

Comment: server-side? HttpCore is used for making requests to servers from clients. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: why do you need to use entity, use getAttribute of HttpRequest object.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some confusion. You are sending requests from a browser to the server. The server is likely using the servlet API. There you handle requests using the `doPost(..)` method of an `HttpServlet`. You have an `HttpServletRequest` from which you can get the parameters - `request.getParameter("paramName")`

HttpCore on the other hand is used to make requests, not to handle requests. It is used as an http client (in the role of the browser).